# Identifying feature showing all attributes are '0' on raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have been using the identify tool on QGIS fine all week, i went back to check a value and now everytime i identify the feature the attribute i get is '0'.

Has anyone encountered this issue or know of any possible fix.

See below image - for some background i am trying to see the flood depth from a raster which i can see isn't 0 based on the band colour but i can't get the exact figure.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @GJo! The value `0` shown in your image **does not** show the value of the cell, it is just there to distinguish from multiple rasters if you set the "Mode" to `Top down` for example. If you look down in the same box, you can see you can scroll to the right. The cell value should be shown in the same row as `Band 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and extremely fast response. I assumed it was something painfully obvious, that would be the problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be linked with your layer selection mode. 
Try to set it to "Top Down" at the bottom of the panel. 
Another way to make it work is to make sure that your raster layer is selected before identifying.

Edit : Here the solution was to simply scroll to the right to show the value

Comment: I needed to scroll to the right :D. Joseph nailed it. Thanks

Comment: The easiest solutions are often overlooked! Could you post it as an answer and set it as an accepted answer? That way people can see what was used to solve the problem. Glad you got it working!

Comment: I was thinking about you posting another answer, and then setting this answer as the answer, as mine is not the one that helped you out. Here it is totally undeserved for me!